# Sort Android strings.xml in Alphabetical Order

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, xml-editor

While programming my Android app I just kept inserting elements in strings.xml with no order *whatsoever*. Is there a shortcut key (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> can organize `android:` attributes in an XML layout file) that sorts string elements alphabetically?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For anyone else who bumps into this.  Copy all the string elements, paste into an Excel spreadsheet sort A-Z and then copy and paste back.

Comment: I guess thats the best option.

Comment: Works using Google Sheets too.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a feature in ADT plugin:

[image]

However, it only sort elements in Resources viewer, it doe not modify anything in the original strings.xml file.

Comment: Its not exactly what I was looking for, but its a good help. thanks ;) Still if anyone knows how to organize the strings.xml alphabetically please leave an answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

For those who have access to GNU or similar *nix command-line utils, you can do the following:

```
cat <(head -n 1 strings.xml) <(head strings.xml -n -2 | tail -n +2 | sort ) <(tail -n 2 strings.xml)
```

You may need to tweak the numbers slightly if your `strings.xml` has a larger XML header.

Comment: Desn't work for multiline strings and XML-elements unfortunately :(