# How to sort strings.xml alphabetically in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Hello is there a way to sort the string names alphabetically in strings.xml ?
It should sort it like this

Before

```
 <string name="ccc">CText</string>
 <string name="aaa">AText</string>
 <string name="bbb">BText</string>
```

After

```
 <string name="aaa">AText</string>
 <string name="bbb">BText</string>
 <string name="ccc">CText</string>
```

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: See this blog post shared by Android Studio developers: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/10/rearrange-attributes-in-android-xml-files-with-intellij-idea-13/ A lazy solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/13022926

Comment: Sorry thats not what I am looking for. The rearrange attributes is the right way to go. Need to find out how to set the arrangement although.

Answer (score 69):

I used **AndroidXmlSorter** plugin and it works perfectly for me.

[image]

How to install:
Go to **Android Studio** -> **Preferences** -> **Plugins** and hit **Browse repositories..**
Search for **AndroidXmlSorter**, install and restart your Android Studio. Go to your strings.xml file and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Voila.

Disclaimer: I'm not the author of this plugin, I just found it by chance and I think all the credits should go to the plugin author. The repo is here: https://github.com/roana0229/android-xml-sorter

Comment: Thanks for the plugin, I tried it out, but it seems like it isn't working with AS 2.2+

Comment: Hmm, mine's using Android Studio 2.2.2 on Mac though.

Comment: Windows here. And seems like that project is abandoned anyways.

Comment: Just tried and works perfectly for me on Windows however the shortcut key mentioned doesn't work. I had to right click in my XML then Refactor -> Sort XML by Name.

Comment: Seem that the project is NOT abandoned. At the time of writing this plugin was updated a month ago. Works like a charm on Intellij 2018.2.

Comment: Works in June 2020 with Android Studio 4.0

Comment: Works in March 2021 with Android Studio 4.1

Comment: Not working in Android Studio 4.2.2 :'( ... Anyone knows the latest solution ?

Comment: Works fine in AS Chipmunk.

Comment: Plugin will crash every time, if any comment inserted in xml file, just delete all comments

Answer (score 9):

> For anyone else who bumps into this. Copy all the string elements, paste into an Excel spreadsheet sort A-Z and then copy and paste back.

[[Sort Android strings.xml in Alphabetical Order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13022926/7496549)]

Answer (score 9):

### 2022-09 | Simple plugin free solution:

### Android studio includes option to **sort lines** / **reverse lines**.

1. Highlight lines of code to be sorted
   [unsorted lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPfTI.png)
2. Edit > **sort lines** or Edit > **reverse lines**
   [sort line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boDCF.png)
3. Enjoy (reverse) alphabetical order
   [sorted lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxBFH.png)

Answer (score 5):

There is a plugin called [Lines Sorter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5919?pr=) which can sort selected lines or whole files.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly AndroidXmlSorter doesn't work for me when sorting multi-line strings.

My solution: Sort the `strings.xml` according to my `android_strings_format.xslt` (with xsltproc) and reformat it (with xmllint).

Cons: You have to execute a script. Therefore, it is not a true native feature of Android Studio. But you can easily execute scripts in Android Studio.

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh

sort_xml_file() {
  xsltproc --output "$1" android_strings_format.xslt "$1"
  export XMLLINT_INDENT="    "
  xmllint --format --encode "utf-8" --output "$1" "$1"
}

sort_xml_file "src/main/res/values/strings.xml"
```

The `android_strings_format.xslt` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output 
    method="xml" 
    version="1.0" 
    encoding="UTF-8" 
    indent="yes" 
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/resources">
    <resources>

<xsl:for-each select="string">
<xsl:sort select="@name"/>
<string name="{@name}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
</string>
</xsl:for-each>

</resources>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Works on Manjaro Linux x64.

EDIT: I have found a way to prevent multi-line text. I can enclose the text with quotes. `<string name="available_version_error">"<u>ERRORa</u>"</string>`

Answer (score 0):

I used a XML formatter with an xslt definition - but this was too complex if you also uses plurals.

My solution: writing my own Python script:

```
import re

# add your files here
strings_files = ["path/to/strings.xml"]


# 1. transform the strings.xml file to a dict
# 2. sort the dict
# 3. transform the dict to a strings.xml file
def sort_strings_xml_file(path_to_file: str):
    entries = dict()
    current_entry_name = None

    # read entries from strings.xml file
    with open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            # a new entry was found in the strings.xml file
            if line.strip().startswith("<string ") or line.strip().startswith("<plurals "):
                current_entry_name = re.search(r'name="(.+)"', line).group(1)
                entries[current_entry_name] = ""

            # store content for the current entry
            if current_entry_name is not None:
                entries[current_entry_name] += line

            # stop recording for the current entry
            if line.strip().endswith("</string>") or line.strip().endswith("</plurals>"):
                current_entry_name = None

    entries = dict(sorted(entries.items()))

    # write results back to the strings.xml file
    with open(path_to_file, "w") as file:
        file.write(('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
                    '<resources>'
                    f'{"".join(entries.values())}</resources>'))

    print(f"{path_to_file} was sorted")


for strings_file in strings_files:
    sort_strings_xml_file(strings_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

i would turn them to ASCII then sort that one and turn them back to string, very easy and very effective

Answer (score -2):

Update: Easiest way is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

For configuration: In Android studio, you can quickly sort XML code by following step:

1. Select all XML code in a file by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Use combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
3. Select "Selected text" + "Rearrange code" Then Press RUN

[image: View Image here]

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't work at my editor Android Studio 3.1.2.

Comment: AFAIK, this only works for attributes in a single element. Not moving elements around.